# Meaning of Hazardous Fractions

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I have encountered this sentence and I wonder what does the words "hazardous fractions" mean?

Is it even the right word in the first place?

Here is the sentence:

> Are you aware that some **hazardous fractions** in e-waste need a special treatment in order to be safely disposed of?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_(chemistry) .

Comment: ...I was really hoping this was going to be a mathematics related question when I saw the title....

Comment: @adam I think 1.7/4 is a hazardous fraction. :-)

Comment: @Jay: I think **19/95, 26/65,** and **16/64** are much more scary! They're trying to convince us we can reduce a fraction to its simplest form merely by striking out whatever digit appears in both the numerator and the denominator - so we'll be lulled into a false sense of security, thinking fractions are *easy!*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Fractions" is used in engineering and medicine, particularly fields that deal with chemistry, to refer to parts of a total quantity that share attributes.  In blood, for instance, the three primary factions are plasma, white blood cells and red blood cells. ([Wiki: Blood Fractionation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_fractionation))

Wikipedia defines the related term, *[Fractional Distillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_distillation)* as *separation of a mixture into its component parts, or **fractions**.*

In the petroleum industry, the fractions would be various grades of oils, gasoline, kerosene, asphalt, paraffin, etc.

In liquor distilling, the fractions are the (most drinkable) center cut, the verging-on-poisonous heads and the oily, rancid tails.

I read the sentence as *Are you aware that some definable sub-portion of e-waste is hazardous and needs a special treatment in order to be safely disposed of?*

Comment: Fractional distillation is the root of the other two usages.

Comment: so e-waste is some sort of e-ffluent?

Comment: I assume *"e-waste"* is a shortening of *"environmental waste"*.

Answer (score 3):

"Fraction" here means "segment, part, subset". The sentence means that, in a given collection of (hazardous) e-waste, there are going to be certain parts that require special treatment — a certain percentage or fraction of them, even. For example, 1 out of every 5 parts (1/5) might be a CRT monitor.